# Azure functions local development

Tags: azure, local, azure-functions, paas

Is there a way that I can configure an azure function which is developed and running on local azure runtime to talk Azure DB sql sever. In the azure portal I could use App Settings to configure and use System.Configuration to get setting from the App Settings. I could not find any App.config or Web.config files when I create a new function App Project in VS 2017. I could hard code the connection string but I was wondering is there a better way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what [the `local.settings.json` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#local-settings-file) is for. It is used to store the settings you would store at the [Azure Functions Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings) level when running out in Azure.